# Laravel get models two descendant levels via pivot tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am using Laravel v4.1... yes I know it is old.  My question is how to set up my models & go about getting related models that are "two" levels away & associated by two pivot tables.

For example...

My database tables:

**firsts**:

```
id  name
==  =============
1   lorem
2   ipsum
```

**seconds**:

```
id  name
==  =============
3   dolor
4   sit
```

**thirds**:

```
id  name
==  =============
5   amet
6   consectetur
7   adipiscing
8   elit
```

**first_second**:

```
first_id  second_id
========  =========
1         3
2         4
```

**second_third**:

```
second_id  third_id
=========  ========
3          5
3          6
4          7
4          8
```

If **FirstModel** is 1, then I would like to get the following from **ThirdModel**:

```
id  name
==  =============
5   amet
6   consectetur
```

I can do it for one level away (ie, **SecondModel**). Any ideas as to how to do it for **ThirdModel**?

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc in 4.1 there was has-many-through, so you might try something like this:

```
class FirstModel extends ModelAbstract
{
    public function seconds()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(SecondModel::class);
    }

    public function thirds()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(ThirdModel::class, SecondModel::class);
    }
}

class SecondModel extends ModelAbstract
{
    public function thirds()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(ThirdModel::class);
    }
}

class ThirdModel extends ModelAbstract {}
```

And then get the data for third relationship from the first like this:

```
$first = FirstModel::find(1);
$thirds = $first->thirds;
```

If that doesn't work, you could do it the old fashion way where you collect all third item ids from the relationships and query the manually:

```
$first = FirstModel::with(['seconds.thirds'])->find(1);
$thirdIds = $first->seconds->map(function ($item) {
    return $item->thirds->pluck('id')->toArray();
})->toArray();
$thirds = ThirdModel::whereIn('id', array_flatten($thirdIds));
```

Answer (score 0):

@thefallen,

Not sure why neither your first method nor your second method did not worked for me.  I ended up going with a hybrid of the two with some extra loops.  Not the cleanest / prettiest but it gets the job done.

```
$results = [] ;
$id = 1 ;
$first = FirstModel :: with( [ 'seconds.thirds' ] ) -> find( $id ) ;
$seconds = $first -> seconds -> map( function ( $item ) {
    return $item -> thirds ;
} ) -> toArray() ;
foreach ( $seconds as $item1 ) {
    foreach ( $item1 as $item2 ) {
        $results[ $item2[ 'id' ] ] = $item2[ 'name' ] ;
    }
}
```